# Windows service can't read appsetttings in OnStart method

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration, windows-services

I wrote a custom Windows service to deal with some file cleanup, editing, etc. In the OnStart method of this program, I have:

```
timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
timer.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["RunInterval"]) * 60 * 60 * 1000);  //yeah, i know its an old method
timer.Enabled = true;
```

but the AppSettings["RunInterval"] is returning null every time, even though I have:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="RunInterval" value="8" />
    <!-- Lots of other stuff -->
</appSettings>
```

in the .exe.config. Why is it doing this? Are the config filed not loaded until after OnStart? Seems like that wouldn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely read app.config settings in an OnStart handler. There must be something else going on. Have you verified that your value is indeed present in the app.config in the bin folder?

Comment: Actually, you may want to try ConfigurationManager.AppSettings over ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings - I use the former all the time in services.

Comment: I'll try that in a few minutes, but I've been using the old method for a while now just because I didn't want to change every instance of it in my code and i didn't want to use them both, and I never had any problems with it. Granted it was in MVC apps rather than windows services, but I can't imagine it causing this issue

Answer (score 0):

Which version of C# are you using?  System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings [is deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsettings.aspx) starting in .NET 2.0.  Use [System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0):

<del>I had this exact same issue. Trying to pull a value from applicationSettings or indeed appsettings did not work in the OnStart method.</del>

<del>I eventually moved the pulling of the config data from the OnStart method to the constructor of the windows service, which did work.</del>

Scratch that, my entire problem was caused by a config problem. Including a defaultDatabase was causing the problem. I'm not sure why, probably missing a Patterns and Practices dll.

```
<dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="LiveDatabase"/>
```